# Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to add a drop down list which will call the data of a particular field of table in db, and show it, then when I click on the list, some data will be shown accordingly.

Now the problem is, I did good in first two lists, then when I testing my third list, it will show "Unknown column 'alumn.work.field' in 'where clause'".

Below is my code to call the variable from my table in database:

```
// Start : Job list
mysql_select_db($database_cnJw, $cnJw);
$query_rs_job = "SELECT field FROM alumn_work";
$rs_job = mysql_query($query_rs_job, $cnJw) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_job = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_job);
$totalRows_rs_job = mysql_num_rows($rs_job);
// End  : Job list
```

and here is the code to add the drop down list:

```
<select name="alumn_work_field">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>

<?php
    do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_rs_job['field']?>">;
    <?php echo $row_rs_job['field']?></option>
<?php
    } 
    while ($row_rs_job = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_job));
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_job);
       if($rows &gt; 0) {
           mysql_data_seek($rs_job, 0);
           $row_rs_job = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_job);
       }
?>;
</select>
```

I myself think the problem will be occur here:

```
 <select name="alumn_work_field">;
```

but I not sure what is the problem. Can anyone tel me what is the problem?

Comment: Check ur DB and make sure the column exists thre !

Comment: I can't see any `WHERE` clause in your `$query_rs_job`. Are you sure you're showing the right piece of code? (And, no, you can't get the error from the HTML tag.)

Comment: Could you show the actual SQL where the error is happening?

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: For formatting help, click the big fat orange question mark on the right of the formatting toolbar.  The button with the curly braces is the thing to use to post a block of code.  No need to manually neuter HTML.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @Peru the column does exists.

Comment: @Amadan but I though the WHERE should be use only when you want to add conditions when searching the db? Something like (WHERE field='doctor')?

Comment: @linfavourite: You are correct. However, "unknown column in WHERE clause" cannot exist unless you have a `WHERE` clause, which leads me to believe the error is not where you think it is.

Comment: @Amadan I actually thinking if the problem occur because the underline of my table name "alumn_work", which cause the code error, since in the tag select, the format is "table_column". Is this possible to happen?

Comment: @linfavourite: Let me say this again: **the only way** to get "unknown column in WHERE clause" is if you execute a query to the database with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Amadan I get what you want to say, but the problem is, I didn't use any WHERE in this particular list, so I really not sure how this error occur.

Comment: @linfavourite: Occam's razor: Your problem is not in this particular list.